# Constraints Removing SegmentController from view

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, constraints, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a `UICollectionView` and a `SegmentController`.

The required end result:

`SegmentController` fully in view, `UICollectionView` beneath it

Before adding constraints:

[image]

After adding constraints (Notice the `SegmentController` is almost entirely hidden):

[image]

The Constraints added:

ProductsCollection.removeConstraints(ProductsCollection.constraints)
    SegmentController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    SegmentController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    SegmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100),
    //ProductsCollection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SegmentController.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
    ProductsCollection.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    ProductsCollection.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    ProductsCollection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
    ])
```

I am guessing the problem is I did not add SegmentController constraints, but I had same result when I added :

```
SegmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100),
SegmentController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
```

Edit:

This view inherits from another one, which has :

```
    private func createProductsCollection()
        {
            let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
            layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 250)

            self.ProductsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

            ProductsCollection.dataSource = self
            ProductsCollection.delegate = self
            ProductsCollection.register(ProductsCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "product_collection_cell")
            ProductsCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            self.view.addSubview(ProductsCollection)

ProductsCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: -50), //leaving space for search field
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 0),
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
                ])
        }
```

EDIT #2:

I am now using these constraints:

```
SegmentController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        SegmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        SegmentController.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        SegmentController.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        SegmentController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        self.view.addSubview(ProductsCollection)
        ProductsCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        ProductsCollection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.SegmentController.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        ProductsCollection.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        ProductsCollection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        ProductsCollection.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

And my view now looks like :

[image]

Comment: have you tried to give your segment control a heigh constraint and width constraint?

Comment: @Osman I don't think so. Can you show me how ? I need my UISegmentController to appear below the Nav controller

Comment: Here's how you give a height to your segmented controller: `SegmentController.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)`. Just use whatever constant you wish.

Comment: Adding height constraint didn't help.

Comment: @dfd As this didn't help - do you have any other suggestion ?

Comment: Not specifically. Auto layout is rough to debug. So first, could you create a new project, copy/paste *everything* that matters (yeah yeah, MCVE) into something, and duplicate it? If so - please do your best to post it. I'd be happy to try to help you. And since the issue isn't related to a `UICollectionView`? Get rid of it. Use (like done in the answer by @Sh_Khan) make it a simple `UIView` with a red background. Start simple, duplicate it, and if you figure it out on your own? Great. But if you have something down to the **basic** issue, edit. That's my best suggestion....

Comment: Let me add some more information to the question, I'll reply here once it is done :)

Comment: There, I added an "edit" that I forgot before - from this view's superview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your constraints are not correct. It should not be `self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor` It should be `self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`. Check what exactly safe area guide gives. From Apple:

> The layout guide representing the portion of your view that is
>   unobscured by bars and other content.

From that it is easy to get that it is the area inside of the "margins".

**EDIT**

```
        self.view.addSubview(segmentController)
        segmentController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        segmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        segmentController.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
        segmentController.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 120).isActive = true
        segmentController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.segmentController.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
```

You will also need to remove this frame

```
self.ProductsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
```

Change it to `frame: .zero` And the contraints should do the rest

Comment: Tanks, but I have tried it before (See comment above), it didn't work :/ I'll check it out again

Comment: I updated my post with this suggestion as it is what I have atm. Still doesn't work..

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the fact I am setting item layout ?

Comment: Did you add the height constraint to the segment controller? If it doesn't have a height it will never be displayed correctly

Comment: When I tried adding height constraints it didn't work either.  But if you want to tell me what exactly to write so we can check it out, please do :)

Comment: Normally I would do something like the edit. It works fine, but probably in your case the constraints from the storyboard are interfering with the programatic constraints

Comment: I used your suggestion, please see Edit 2 :)

Comment: Edit #2 in my post

Comment: You need to remove this line as well:  NSLayoutConstraint(item: ProductsCollection, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 20)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180559/discussion-between-ofri-and-galo-torres-sevilla).

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      SegmentController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
      SegmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100),
      ProductsCollection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SegmentController.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
      ProductsCollection.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
      ProductsCollection.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
      ProductsCollection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Note top of segment should be hooked with top of view not bottom as you did here

```
SegmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor,
```

//

```
let SegmentController = UISegmentedControl(items: ["Safe","Ask"])

let ProductsCollection = UIView()

ProductsCollection.backgroundColor = .red

view.addSubview(SegmentController)

view.addSubview(ProductsCollection)

SegmentController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

ProductsCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    SegmentController.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
    SegmentController.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 100),
    ProductsCollection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SegmentController.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
    ProductsCollection.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor),
    ProductsCollection.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor),
    ProductsCollection.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
])
```

[image]

Comment: I might have not stated, but I want the UISegmentController to appear below the navigation bar..

Comment: I have added the constraints you gave me but result is the same

Comment: do you set items array fro the segment ??

Comment: As pointed out in the comments to the question, there is no height constraint defined for the `UISegementedButton`.

Comment: @dfd no need for it

Comment: I've had to give it one at times - otherwise the result is what the OP has pictured. It's not necessarily "nearly hidden", it has "virtually no height".

Comment: it contains buttons which have an intrinsic content size

Comment: I will try your new suggestion :)

Comment: I have added SegmentController.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

ProductsCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

And the constraints you wrote - still didn't fix this...

Comment: Maybe it is because my ProductsCollection is defined in super view ?

Comment: I am using "ProductsCollection.removeConstraints(ProductsCollection.constraints)" before applying new constraints tho

Comment: @Sh_Khan Do you have any other suggestions ?

Comment: Also, I just noticed that this line makes my SegmentController disappear:

ProductsCollection.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: SegmentController.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),

Comment: While I *think* I understand enough of intrinsic size :-) I also remember seeing this issue in an app of mine and did what I suggested. But I withdraw my earlier comments, particularly with what you edited with. (I would have thought intrinsic size would have fixed my problem but it didn't. I probably had a different issue that a height constraint did what what was needed to (not just) fix (but obscure) the underlying cause.

Comment: @Ofri all code inside **viewDidLayoutSubviews** should be at end of **createProductsCollection** as **viewDidLayoutSubviews** is called many times

Comment: @Sh_Khan I moved code to createProductsCollection, still didn't fix the problem..

Comment: where you call it ,  please share all code relevant , note you current constraints fill the screen with the collection

Comment: @Sh_Khan I Have updated my post with "Edit", and shared code from super view

Comment: @Sh_Khan Maybe it has something to do with the fact I am setting item layout ?

Comment: Please notice I opened chat in last reply to my post