# The correct methodology for UICollectionView filtering

Tags: swift, performance, uicollectionview, filtering

I just implemented a filtering mechanism in my `UICollectionView` and I think this is not the correct methodology I should have chosen.

How can I improve my code to make it have better performance?

I have a screen where you input your criterias for filtering, and then this code handles the rest:

```
extension ProductsCollectionViewController
{
    @objc func Filter()
    {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue_to_filter_view", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func unwindFromFilterScreenAccept(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
    {
        if segue.source is FilterViewController
        {
            if let senderVC = segue.source as? FilterViewController
            {
                if senderVC.chosenCategory != "" {categoryFilter = senderVC.chosenCategory}
                self.areFiltersSet = true
            }
        }

        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false

        self.products.removeAll()
        self.LoadProducts(productsToShow: pageType)
        //self.LoadProducts(productsToShow: pageType)

    }

    @IBAction func unwindFromClearAllFilters(segue: UIStoryboardSegue)
    {
        ClearAllFilters()
        self.products.removeAll()
        self.LoadProducts(productsToShow: pageType)
    }

    private func ClearAllFilters()
    {
        areFiltersSet = false
    }

    private func FilterProduct(prod: Product) -> Bool
    {
        if areFiltersSet == false {return true}
        return FilterProductByCategory(prod:prod) && FilterProductByLocation(prod:prod) && FilterProductByCondition(prod:prod)
    }
```

Also:

I have a search bar implemented. Will the two work together? Is there a way to properly integrate the two?

P.S:

The Filtering itself is checked when adding a product to the collection when loading products.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filtering by performing a segue is not the best way. It will be better to update the collectionView itself depending on the filter that you choose. For example, if you have products that correspond to a specific category you can just do something like:

```
let products = [Product(category: "one"), Product(category: "one"), Product(category: "two")]
let foo = products.filter {$0.category == "one"}
```

that filter function will return only the products that correspond to category one. Then you can just use the filtered array to populate the collectionView.

About the searchBar, yes, they will work together with any other filter function. Basically you will just perform two filters:

1. Based on the category property
2. Based on the substring that you input

Just for future reference, if you add the searchBar as collectionViewCell or as header you will HAVE to reload items with the indexPaths because `reloadData()` will resign the responder from the searchBar.

One more thing, just as a suggestion, it is a common practice to name your methods with lowercase -> filter() instead of Filter().

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is there also a way to "unfilter", after a filter ? Or do I need to reload all products

Comment: You can just populate the collectionView with the not filtered array instead of the filtered one and reloadData() in the collectionView

Comment: Good idea, I'll try this :)

Can you also please take a look here :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387101/constraints-removing-segmentcontroller-from-view/52387246?noredirect=1#comment91732753_52387246

Comment: I answered it. Please check